# IntelliJ IDEAとAndroid Studioの違い

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Javaの開発を以前まではEclipseで行っていましたが興味もあってAndroidの開発をするときにAndroid Studioをインストールしました。

私的にはかなり気に入っているのですが、また再びJavaの開発をしようとしたらEclipseが使えなくなっていることに気づきました。
EclipseとAndroid Studio両方インストールしておいてもいいのですが、せっかくならJavaの開発もIntelliJ IDEAでやってしまえばいいのではないかと思いました。

そこで質問なのですが、Androidの開発をするにあたってIntelliJ IDEA(無料版)とAndroid Studioに差はあるでしょうか？
なければIntelliJ IDEAで統一したいと思っています。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ほとんど差はなさそうですね。
となると疑問に思うことなのですが、IntelliJ IDEAでjavaもAndroid開発もことたりるのであればandroidstudioの存在意義が全然ないように感じるのですが、今後は2つのIDEは別々の進化をしていくものと考えることができるのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問にコメントするのではなく、回答にコメントしたほうが回答者に通知されるのでお勧めです。

Answer (score 3):

Ultimate Editionの話で、Community Editionは使ったことが無いため参考にならないかもしれません。

以前はAndroid Studioの最新版で実装されていた機能やBugfixがIntelliJ IDEAの最新版に反映されるのが遅く、IDEA上からは古いバージョンのandroid-gradle-pluginを使わざるを得ないことも有りましたが、
2015年4月現在ではチーム内でAndroid StudioとIntelliJ IDEAの環境差があっても問題なく開発できる状態になっています。